# How to launch JBoss on Win7?

Tags: jboss6.x

i tried to launch it by cmd with this command:

C:...\jboss-eap-6.4.0\bin>standalone.bat

but it failed with error:

> Error occured during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

how to launch JBoss? i did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss could be trying to use more memory than it's permitted by Java's memory range. You can try increasing the heap size.

Add this to your standalone.bat before running it again:

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"